I am having problems generating a cmake file for pico-rvd
I am trying to build pico-rvd, but I am having trouble creating the cmake files. Here are the version number for my tools.
cmake version 3.31.0-rc3

C:\Users\Matthew>mingw32-make --version
GNU Make 4.4.1

g++ (Rev3, Built by MSYS2 project) 14.1.0

gcc (Rev3, Built by MSYS2 project) 14.1.0

I can use these tools to build other repos, but when I try to make the cmake files for pico-rvd it fails with this error.
PS C:\Users\Matthew\Desktop\Pico\pico-rvd\build> cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" ..
Using PICO_SDK_PATH from environment ('C:\Users\Matthew\Desktop\Pico\pico-sdk')
PICO_SDK_PATH is C:/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk
Target board (PICO_BOARD) is 'yd_rp2040'.
Using board configuration from C:/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-rvd/src/boards/yd_rp2040.h
Defaulting platform (PICO_PLATFORM) to 'rp2040' since not specified.
-- Defaulting build type to 'Release' since not specified.
Defaulting compiler (PICO_COMPILER) to 'pico_arm_cortex_m0plus_gcc' since not specified.
Configuring toolchain based on PICO_COMPILER 'pico_arm_cortex_m0plus_gcc'
Defaulting PICO_GCC_TRIPLE to 'arm-none-eabi'
CMake Error at C:/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/cmake/preload/toolchains/util/find_compiler.cmake:29 (message):
  Compiler 'arm-none-eabi-gcc' not found, you can specify search path with
  "PICO_TOOLCHAIN_PATH".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/cmake/preload/toolchains/util/find_compiler.cmake:39 (pico_find_compiler)
  C:/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/cmake/preload/toolchains/util/pico_arm_gcc_common.cmake:25 (pico_find_compiler_with_triples)
  C:/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/cmake/preload/toolchains/pico_arm_cortex_m0plus_gcc.cmake:7 (include)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.31/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:146 (include)
  C:/Users/Matthew/FreeRTOS-Kernel/portable/ThirdParty/GCC/RP2040/CMakeLists.txt:17 (project)


CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "MinGW Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

I have the paths to cmake, mingw32-make, gcc, and g++ added to my environment variables. I can enter any of those onto the commandline and get an output. I also tried with nmake to no avail. I would appreciate any help I can get.

A Pico project needs cross-compiler, for being able to be compiled for the target platform. Regular gcc, which compiles for the host platform, is not suitable.
